# No device available in AVD to run API level 23 of android

Tags: android, xamarin

How can I add more devices in android virtual device to support higher API levels of android like 23,24 etc.?I am using Xamarin with Visual Studio and android sdk.

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-emulator/google-emulator-manager/) to add more devices.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe. This helped